# How to loop through array of objects from Firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am trying to loop through an array object retrived from Firebase:

```
   var announcementsRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+'/annoucements');
   $scope.announcements =  $firebaseObject(announcementsRef);
```

I display it in console :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szfqa.png).

I tried to display the first object message like this

```
console.log($scope.announcements[1].message).
```

But it does not shows me
How can I solve this ?

Comment: Is it an array, or an object? It makes difference.

Comment: Using `console.log()` for debugging AngularFire data loading is not recommended. To see your announcements, make them visible in your HTML with `<pre>{{ announcements | json}}</pre>`. That pattern is recommended in the [Intro to AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html#section-async-intro) section of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If what's stored on Firebase it's an array, the way to use it is with `$firebaseArray(ref);`

Check the guide for more info https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html

Comment: @CarmenMitruStudent why do you consider this non help? It is actually exactly what you need to do. If the data at the location is a collection of objects, you need to wrap it in `$firebaseArray()` and bind that to your `$scope`.